# C# only use arrays if it exists

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I am a beginner in programming. And now I'm facing a task where I can't get any further. Probably it is relatively easy to solve.

This is what I want to do: I read out a .txt file and there are several lines of content.

Example what is in the .txt file:

```
text1,text2,text3
text1,text2,
text1,text2,text3,text4
```

I'm now ready to find the right line and use it. Then I want to split the line and assign each text to its own string.

I can do this if I know that this line have 4 words. But what if I don't know how many words this line have.

For example if I want to assign 5 strings but there are only 4 arrays in the column I get an error.

My program currently looks like this:

```
string reader = "text1,text2,text3,text4";
string[] words = reader.Split(',');

string word1 = words[0].ToString();
string word2 = words[1].ToString();
string word3 = words[2].ToString();
string word4 = words[3].ToString();

textBox1.Text = word3;
```

My goal is to find out how many words are in the string. And then pass each word to a separate string.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't think about trying to assign to separate variables - you already have a way of accessing each string - e.g. `words[2]` gives you access to the third string. (Also, no need to `ToString()` on something that's already a string)

Comment: You can see how many words a line has by checking `words.Length`

Comment: You probably want to keep your strings in an array to be honest.

Comment: What if array has, say, `1234` words (imagine that I've provided a small narration)? Do you really want `1234` *local variables*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if you want separated *local variables* like `word1`, `word2` etc. To see why, let's
bring the idea to the *point of absurdity*. Imagine, that we have a *small narration* with `1234`
words only. Do we really want to create `word1, word2, ..., word1234` local variables?

So, let's stick to a single `words` array only:

```
  string[] words = reader.Split(',');
```

Now, you can easily get array `Length` (i.e. number of items):

```
  textBoxCount.Text = $"We have {words.Length} words in total";
```

Or get N-th `word` (let `N` be *one based*) from the `words` array:

```
  string wordN = array.Length >= N ? array[N - 1] : "SomeDefaultValue";
```

In your case (3d word) it can be

```
  // either 3d word or an empty string (when we have just two less words) 
  textBox1.Text = array.Length >= 3 ? array[3 - 1] : "";
```

Technically, you can use *Linq* and query the `reader` string:

```
  using System.Linq;
  
  ...

  // 3d word or empty string
  textBox1.Text = reader.Split(',').ElementAtOrDefault(3 - 1) ?? "";
```

But Linq seems to be overshot here.

Answer (score 2):

To get the length of the Array, you can easily use .Length

In your example, you just write

int arraylength = words.Length;

I don't understand, why do you want to create a new String for every value of the string-array? You can just use them in the array.

In your example you always user .ToString(), this isn't necessary because you already have a string.

An array is just multiple variables (in your example strings) which are connected to another.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you for your answer. I can use the arrys I have.
But in the end I only want to spend as many arrys as I have.
Maybe it will be easier with a console example.

Code:
string reader = "text1,text2,text3,text4";
string[] words = reader.Split(',');

string word1 = words[0].ToString();
string word2 = words[1].ToString();
string word3 = words[2].ToString();
string word4 = words[3].ToString();

Output window:
text1
text2
text3
text4

But if I only have 3 or 5 characters. I would either not display everything or get an error because the 5th does not exist.

Comment: @Alex So check `words.Length`, and don't try and access `words[5]` unless `words` contains at least 6 elements

Comment: Use a loop to display them.

EXAMPLE :
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
}